# Spin Connection Vanishes?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, spinors

I'm trying to reproduce a result for the components of the spin connection in FRW spacetime. The formula for the spin connection $\Gamma_{\mu}$ is
$$\Gamma_{\mu} = \frac{1}{2} \Sigma^{a b} L_{a}^{\nu} L_{b \nu, \; \mu}$$

Where $\Sigma^{ab} = \frac{1}{4}[\gamma^{a},\gamma^{b}]$ are Lorentz group generators and $L_{a}^{\mu}$ is the vierbein. If I try to use this formula for the Conformally Flat FRW spacetime with metric $$d s^{2}=a^{2}(t)\left[-d \tau^{2}+\left(d x^{1}\right)^{2}+\left(d x^{2}\right)^{2}+\left(d x^{3}\right)^{2}\right],$$

I know I should get the following answer:
$$\Gamma_{t}=0, \quad \Gamma_{x^{i}}=-\frac{\dot{a}}{2 a} \gamma^{i} \gamma^{0}$$

based on a paper I've been reading https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.30.2573 (I have access through my University), but I keep getting zero for *all* components of $\Gamma_{\mu}$ . It seems to me that the problem lies in the fact that the Lorentz group generators are antisymmetric, whilst the vierbeins are symmetric. I don't know how to remedy this, clearly I'm going wrong somewhere. Any advice/direction is welcome!

Comment: What do you mean that the vierbeins are symmetric, could you state this explicitly? Also small note, you've made a typo on your FRW metric.

Comment: When I say the vierbein is symmetric, I mean its components can be written in a symmetric 4x4 matrix. I should also note that the vierbein is diagonal. Also, I have fixed the typo on the metric, thank you for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is good exercise for me. Please tell me if I made any mistakes.

The vierbein are
$$
L_0^\mu=\frac{1}{a(t)}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad
L_1^\mu=\frac{1}{a(t)}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad...
$$
The nonzero Chrstoffel symbols are
$$
\Gamma^t_{tt}=3\frac{\dot a}{a},\quad
\Gamma^t_{ii}=\frac{\dot a}{a}, \quad
\Gamma^i_{it}=\Gamma^i_{ti}=\frac{\dot a}{a}.
$$
To compute for example $\Gamma_1$, we need $L_{a,1}^\mu$. They are
$$
L_{a=0,1}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\dot a/a^2\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad
L_{a=1,1}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}\dot a/a^2\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\quad
L_{a=2\text{ or }3,1}^\mu=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.
$$
So $\Gamma^\nu_a\Gamma_{b\nu,i=1}$ is (you may forgot the minus sign here)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0&\dot a/a&0&0\\
-\dot a/a&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
After contraction with $\Sigma^{ab}$, this gives the correct answer.

Comment: Ahh, so did you take the covariant derivative of the vierbein?

Comment: Yes, denoted by $L_{a,1}^\mu$.